# React-router outlet confusion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Why my outlet is not working in `react-router-dom`. All my components worked fine until I use `Outlet` and after using outlet my navigation component is not showing while other component seems to render.

```
import Home from "./Routes/Home/Home.component";
import { Routes, Route, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>Hello I am Navigation!!!</h1>
      </div>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
};

const Shop = () => {
  return <h2>I am shop component</h2>
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Navigation />} />
      <Route index element={<Home />} />
      <Route path='shop' element={<Shop />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I am receiving this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXI7S.jpg)

and I want navigation component to render all above and persist every time I navigate to elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

for using of Outlet you need Add children to Route Component

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Navigation/>}>
          <Route path="url1" element{<ChildElemnt1 />} />
          <Route path="url2" element{<ChildElemnt2 />} />
          <Route path="url3" element{<ChildElemnt3 />} />
          ...
        </Route>
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='shop' element={<Shop/>}/>
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Navigation` component isn't rendered as a layout route with nested routes, so nothing is rendered into the `Outlet` it is rendering. `Navigation` will also only render on path `"/"`.

If you want the `Navigation` component to render *always* then you can render it alone outside the routes.

```
const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>Hello I am Navigation!!!</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Navigation />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/'>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path='shop' element={<Shop />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
};
```

Or you can utilize it as a layout route such that it wraps nested routes that render their `element` into the `Outlet`.

```
const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>Hello I am Navigation!!!</h1>
      </div>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Navigation />} />
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='shop' element={<Shop />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
};
```